# Hive Query array as field

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have two Hive table :

Client Table :

```
id,name,salary 
1 ,John, 10000
2 ,Melissa, 5000
```

Account Table :

```
id,account_number,client_id
1 ,00920202, 1
2 ,00920203, 1
3 ,00920204, 1
4 ,00920205, 2
5 ,00920206, 2
```

I need a hive query that return this results :

```
id,name,salary,accounts
1 ,John, 10000, {00920202, 00920203, 00920204}
2 ,Melissa, 5000, {00920205, 00920206}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collect_list` if you are sure the account numbers are unique. Else use `collect_set` which eliminates duplicates.

```
select c.id,c.name,c.salary,collect_list(a.account_number) as all_accounts
from client c
join account a on a.client_id=c.id
group by c.id,c.name,c.salary
```